# How can I input the csv into mysql correctly?

Tags: mysql

I have created a database in mysql as

```
create credit_facility (
    id varchar(5) not null,     
    borrower varchar(6) not null, 
    category varchar(40) not null, 
    purpose varchar(30) not null, 
    committed varchar(6) not null, 
    value_date date not null, 
    maturity_date date not null, 
    currency varchar(6) not null, 
    extension varchar(2) not null, 
    co_borrower int not null);
```

and I tried to input csv into mysql with following codes

```
set global local_infile=1; 
use credit_facility; 
load data local infile "/Users/lingleiqi/Desktop/test.csv" 
into table credit_facility 
ignore 1 lines;
```

my test.csv looks as follows

```
id  borrower  category   purpose    committed    value_date     maturity_date     currency      extension  co_borrower
1   abc       credit     general    uncommitted  2023-11-12     2023-12-1         USD           no         xyz
2   efg       credit     general    uncommitted  2023-12-10     2022-09-04        EUR           no         hij
```

however, after execute the code, the datebase turned out to be

```
id  borrower  category   purpose    committed    value_date     maturity_date     currency      extension  co_borrower
1,abc                                            0000-00-00     0000-00-00                                  0
2,efg                                            0000-00-00     0000-00-00                                  0
```

and the mysql remark that
1265 data truncated for column "id" at row 1 1261 row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns 1261 row 1 doesn't ....
Can anyone show me how to remedy it? Thanks in advance

i have searched in internet but can not find a solution. Can anyone teach me how to upload it?

Comment: Try MySQL Workbench so you can do it with a few clicks.

Comment: `load data local infile` expects columns separated by a tab character.  Are your columns separated by a tab, or are there just spaces?  Is that LITERALLY what your CSV looks like (which is not a CSV at all, of course).

Comment: I don't see where the comma in `1,abc` and `2,efg` is coming from. It's not in the file, and there's no code in the `LOAD DATA` to add it.